# Set Condition echo function get_post_meta

Tags: post-meta, wpdb

I want to try echo marks of the specific quiz by name

I have two quiz for each course.

- Quiz One
- Quiz Two

I call a function to echo marks

```
global $wpdb;
$marks = get_post_meta($course_id,$member_id, true);
echo $marks
```

that's print all marks for every quiz

How I echo only Quiz One's marks and table (Test De Personnalite)?

Here my Table

[image: Screenshot Table]

Header tabel code

```
          <th>
                    <?php
                         if($flag >= 1){
                            foreach($quiz_ids as $quiz_id){
                                echo '<th><a href="'.get_permalink($quiz_id).'" target="_blank">'.get_the_title($quiz_id).'</a></th>';
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                    </th>
```

Output table Code

```
<?php
                if($flag >= 1){
                    foreach($quiz_ids as $quiz_id){
                        echo '<td>'.get_post_meta($quiz_id,$member_id,true).'</td>';
                    }
                }
                $sum=0;           
                $status = get_user_course_status($member_id,$course_id);
                if($status > 3){
                    $marks = get_post_meta($course_id,$member_id, true);
                    $sum += $marks;
                    echo '<td>'.$marks.'</td>';    
                }else{
                    echo '<td>'._x('N.A','Marks not available in batch statisitcs leaderboard','wplms-batches').'</td>';
                }
                echo '</tr>';
                $i++;
                ?>
```

Comment: you have an array of marks? how is the data of the marks in the post-meta?

Comment: Yes I have an array, but I cant find the data of the marks in post-meta

Comment: Can you share some more details

Comment: I have add more info

Answer (score 0):

From your code, this is the part where you can get the mark, modified to get only one:

```
     $member_id = get_current_user_id();
     $course_id = 1; //i am assuming the ID of the course
     $status = get_user_course_status($member_id,$course_id);
     if($status > 3){
        $mark = get_post_meta($course_id,$member_id, true);
        echo $mark;
     }
```